# log4j2 Exception logging performance

Tags: java, performance, logging, log4j2

We are using log4j2 for logging. After doing initial benchmark I have concluded that for same QPS, logging exception is 80 times slower than logging normal message.

Here is a sample error log message.

```
2022-08-25 11:09:14,699 - [pool-2-thread-1][{id=eb9bcf4f-1dcc-4cd7-8588-fd7916d623b8, path=/hellowworld}] - [Test2] ERROR - error wile doing something important java.lang.RuntimeException: exception
    at Test2.recursiveCount(Test2.java:140) ~[logging.jar:?]
    at Test2.recursiveCount(Test2.java:142) ~[logging.jar:?]
    at Test2.recursiveCount(Test2.java:142) ~[logging.jar:?]
    at Test2.access$000(Test2.java:17) ~[logging.jar:?]
    at Test2$LoggerRunnable.run(Test2.java:75) ~[logging.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_202]
```

Here is a sample log message

```
2022-08-25 18:12:02,125 - [pool-2-thread-1][{id=90e8ebda-e02a-4c48-bc37-560190bda40a, path=/hellowworld}] - [Test2] INFO - adding log with number=ok uuid=1661431322125
```

It could be attributed to

> Note: Logging exceptions and stack traces will create temporary objects with any layout. (However, Layouts will only create these temporary objects when an exception actually occurs.) We haven't figured out a way to log exceptions and stack traces without creating temporary objects. That is unfortunate, but you probably still want to log them when they happen.

[source log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/garbagefree.html)

Are there any config change that can be done to reduce the overhead of exception logging? Like

1. For similar stacktrace errors only log few sample stacktrace and not all the stack traces
2. limiting the deapth of stacktrace?

anything else?

Comment: "For similar stacktrace errors only log few sample stacktrace and not all the stack traces" - that's probably hard to do since log4j would then have to keep track of all errors to see if the stack trace is similar. It's probably easier to just log the stack traces. 

My approach would probably be to reduce the number of stack traces that need to be logged by fixing the unexpected exceptions and not logging stack traces for expected ones.

Comment: since we are talking about higher qps service (for lower qps service logging exception should not be a big issue imo) we may even be fine doing random sampling. If can be handled at framework level(log4j2) without too much code changes.

Comment: It is worth noting that exceptions are not supposed to be performant.  The very creation of an exception and its stack trace has a measurable effect on performance.  This is one reason developers are urged not to use exceptions for flow control (for example, one should check for a valid index with `if` rather than catching IndexOutOfBoundsException).